# Latex, разносортные приложения: как оформить

Tags: pdf, latex, tex

К основному документу есть 5 Приложений:

- Приложение 1(3,4 и 5): выравнивание заголовка по правому краю,
  начертание заголовка не «жирным», отступ от заголовка до основного
  текста - 1,5см, ориентация страницы - книжная, нумерация страниц не
  требуется, поля - 2cm, 2cm, 3cm(левое), 2cm.
- Приложение 2: выравнивание заголовка по правому краю, начертание
  заголовка не «жирным», отступ от заголовка до основного текста -
  1,5см, ориентация страницы - альбомная, нумерация страниц вида «стр.
  1 из N» (без кавычек), поля - 0,5 см.

Так как ни разу не имел опыта формирования приложений в LateX, то и минимально работающего примера дать не могу.

Прошу помочь с оформлением.